# Let $f$ be an entire function such that $f(z) = f(1/z)$ for all $z \in \mathbb{C} \setminus \{0\}$. Show that $f(z)$ is constant.

Tags: complex-analysis, constants

Let $f$ be an entire function such that $f(z) = f(1/z)$ for all $z \in \mathbb{C} \setminus \{0\}$. Show that $f(z)$ is constant.

I understand Liouville's Theorem could come into play here but unsure where to apply.

Comment: Liouville tells us that there exists no non-constant bounded entire function. Try to show that the function is bounded.

Comment: I am not entirely sure how to do that but would it be possible to do this in separate cases z<1 and z>1?

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** $\lim_{z\to\infty} f(z)=\lim_{z\to\infty} f(\frac{1}{z})=f(0)$.

Comment: Is $f(0)$ defined?

Comment: If $f$ is entire then it is defined and holomorphic in the whole complex plane.

Comment: Got it. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The mapping $z\mapsto\frac1z$ is a bijection between the punctured closed disk
$$
\{|z|\le1,z\neq0\}
$$
and what stays outer:
$$
\{|z|\ge1\}.
$$
Thus
$$
\sup_{|z|\ge1}|f(z)|=\sup_{|z|\ge1}|f(1/z)|
=\sup_{|z|\le1,z\neq0}|f(z)|
$$
and the last one is clearly bounded, say by $B$.
Thus
$$
|f(z)|\le\max\{B,|f(0)|\}\;\;\;\;\; \forall z\in\Bbb C.
$$
So you have a bounded entire function, which is constant by Liouville.

Comment: Why is |f(z)| bounded on the punctured disc ?

Comment: Because f is entire, so it is in particular continuous on the whole complex plane, so it is |f|, hence it is bounded on the closed unit ball, so it is on the puntured ball