# Let $f$ be entire an entire function with $f(z)=f(\frac{1}{z})$ for all complex $z$. Prove $f$ is constant.

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $f$ be entire an entire function with $f(z)=f(\frac{1}{z})$
for all complex $z$. Prove $f$ is constant.

I saw joe's answer:

> The mapping $z\mapsto\frac1z$ is a bijection between the punctured
> closed disk $$ \{|z|\le1,z\neq0\} $$ and what stays outer: $$
>  \{|z|\ge1\}. $$ Thus $$ \sup_{|z|\ge1}|f(z)|=\sup_{|z|\ge1}|f(1/z)|
>  =\sup_{|z|\le1,z\neq0}|f(z)| $$ and the last one is clearly bounded, say by $B$. Thus $$ |f(z)|\le\max\{B,|f(0)|\}\;\;\;\;\; \forall
> > z\in\Bbb C. $$ So you have a bounded entire function, which is
> constant by Liouville.

[Let $f$ be an entire function such that $f(z) = f(1/z)$ for all $z \in \mathbb{C} \setminus \{0\}$. Show that $f(z)$ is constant.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3666251/let-f-be-an-entire-function-such-that-fz-f1-z-for-all-z-in-mathbbc)

My questions :

1. $f$ is an entire function meaning that $f$ has no poles , i.e $\forall z_0\in \mathbb{C} \lim_{z\to z_0} f(z)\not\to \infty$ ?
2. why the given $f(z)=f(\frac{1}{z})$ is neccessary?

Thanks.

Comment: 1. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entire_function (Google is your friend). 2. Necessary for what?

Comment: @Gary  Necessary for proving the fact  $f$ is constant.

Comment: Without that, the statement is as follows: "Let $f$  be entire an entire function. Prove $f$ is constant." What do you think?

Comment: $f(z)=f(\frac{1}{z})$ for all complex $z$ does not make sense.